# How-to: reset window "tab" in Haiku?

Tags: window-manager, haiku

I have been running [Haiku](http://haiku-os.org) in various environments now for several months, but have run across an interesting issue: WebPositive (the browser that ships with Haiku) has lost its yellow tab at the top of the window, and only displays in full-screen mode.

How can I reset that behavior? The yellow tab is highly useful, exspecially when needing to shrink the window, since right now I can't change the window size :-|

current "normal" window:
[image: missing yellow tab bar]

full-screened:
[image: missing menus when F11'd]

how it *should* look (fresh install):
[image: see the tab at the top of the window]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand this question correctly, but the full screen mode of WebPositive can be left via <kbd>F11</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Furthermore, there is a small window icon in the top right corner when you move the mouse, that, when pressed, will let you leave full screen as well.

Comment: I'll grab a screenshot of the issue and update the question as soon as I am able

Comment: see question update

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and try

```
hey WebPositive SET Frame of Window 2 to BRect[100,100,600,600]
```

That should at least give you something small enough to drag the yellow tab back into view.